# Using Value In Column As Column Name In Another Search

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL so please correct any terminology mistakes I am making.

Where I am struggling, is understanding how to use the value from a column as the column name in another table.

I have read through the previous questions that Stack Overflow provided prior to my question (among many others) and haven't been able to figure out a common "pattern" between the various JOIN, CASE, UNION, and GROUP BY shown to make any significant progress.

```
CREATE TABLE `activityFieldTable` (
  `ActivityFieldID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ActivityName` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table above defines a list of 'activity' that the user can selected from a dropdown.

```
CREATE TABLE `activityFieldDetailsTable` (
  `ActivityFieldDetailID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ActivityFieldID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DetailName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `DetailType` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DetailValues` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `ActivityTableColumn` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table above allows for each activity to have it's own list of 'question(s)' so when a user selects an activity the table below provides the details needed to create the particular type of input element for the question.  The ActivityTableColumn defines where the 'answer' for the user is to be stored (a column name in the activityTable which is shown below)

```
CREATE TABLE `activityTable` (
  `ActivityID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ActivityFieldID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `AS1` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AS2` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AS3` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AS4` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AS5` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartTime` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `EndTime` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table above is where all the activities entered by the users are stored.  It currently has 5 columns, (AS1..AS5) that can store the 'answers' to the activity specific questions whenever a user enters an activity.

I'm using PHP and think that perhaps providing the pieces of the queries could be helpful to understand what I'm trying to do:

```
$query = "SELECT ActivityTableColumn FROM activityFieldDetailsTable WHERE ActivityFieldID= :ActivityFieldID";
```

- ActivityFieldID above is always a single value but the query above can return up to 5 rows (if 5 questions are defined in the activityFieldDetailsTable for that specific activity).

```
$query1 = "SELECT ($query) FROM activityTable WHERE ActivityID= :ActivityID";
```

- This search would return the value in specific column (AS1, AS2, .. AS5).

```
$query2 = "SELECT activityFieldDetailsTable.DetailName, activityFieldDetailsTable.DetailType, activityFieldDetailsTable.DetailValues, activityFieldDetailsTable.ActivityTableColumn, activityTable.($query) FROM activityFieldDetailsTable WHERE ActivityFieldID= :ActivityFieldID AND ActivityID= :ActivityID";
```

The expected results are:

```
| DetailName | DetailType | DetailValues | ActivityTableColumn | [activityTable.($columnName)] |
| Location | radio | Outside, Inside | AS1 | [values from the 'AS1' column from activityTable] |
| Temperature | text | 10 | AS2 | [values from the 'AS2' column from activityTable] |
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Recommendation, look up how to do `JOINs`, with the right data structures you should be able to do this in a single query. Putting a column name in a data row is a patten that is very hard to make into SQL. If the AS1-5 are fixed, it might be workable

Comment: @danblack - Thanks for the recommendation.  I've done what you suggested, removing columns AS1..AS5 and placed them into a new table and achieved what I was looking to do using `JOINs`.